# closest integer value

Tags: optimization

Find the integer which is closest to the value of

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{5^6+1}- \sqrt[6]{5^6-1}}$

I have tried putting them between n and n+1 and tried manipulating  n but I cant seem to find a strategy.

Comment: A calculator reveals that the value is approximately 9374.9. Could 9375 be the answer?

Comment: Yea its is . Calculators arent allowed in thw contest though (((

Comment: But getting strangers on the internet to provide the answer to you is allowed in the contest?

Answer (score 3):

Put $5^{-6}=:p$. Then your number $x$ satisfies
$$\eqalign{5x&={1\over(1+p)^{1/6}-(1-p)^{1/6}}={(1+p)^{1/6}+(1-p)^{1/6}\over (1+p)^{1/3}-(1-p)^{1/3}}\cr
&={\bigl((1+p)^{1/6}+(1-p)^{1/6}\bigr)\bigl((1+p)^{2/3}+(1-p^2)^{1/3}+(1-p)^{2/3}\bigr)\over2p}\ ,\cr}$$
hence
$$x={5^5\over2}\bigl((1+p)^{1/6}+(1-p)^{1/6}\bigr)\bigl((1+p)^{2/3}+(1-p^2)^{1/3}+(1-p)^{2/3}\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
Since $p$ is terribly small we conjecture that
$$x\approx3\cdot 5^5=9375\ .$$
To make sure we have to develop the RHS of $(1)$ with respect to $p$. Inspection shows that there are no linear terms. We therefore have
$$x=9375\>\bigl(1+O(p^2)\bigr)\ ,$$
so that we may safely proclaim $9375$ as end result. For a full proof you would need estimates for the error in the binomial approximation.